# Firestore single document snapshot stream not updating

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

My Flutter application needs to listen for any changes in a specific Firestore document.

The process is quite simple and is found here in various solutions:

1. **StackOverflow:** [flutter-firestore-how-to-listen-for-changes-to-one-document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53982928/flutter-firestore-how-to-listen-for-changes-to-one-document)
2. **StackOverflow:**[can-i-listen-to-a-single-document-in-firestore-with-a-streambuilder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56509221/can-i-listen-to-a-single-document-in-firestore-with-a-streambuilder)
3. **StackOverflow:**[using-stream-building-with-a-specific-firestore-document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50788549/using-stream-building-with-a-specific-firestore-document)
4. **StackOverflow:** [how-to-get-a-specific-firestore-document-with-a-streambuilder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58473539/how-to-get-a-specific-firestore-document-with-a-streambuilder)
5. **Medium:** [how-to-get-data-from-firestore-and-show-it-on-flutterbuilder-or-streambuilder-e05](https://dev.to/kazuhideoki/how-to-get-data-from-firestore-and-show-it-on-flutterbuilder-or-streambuilder-e05)

These are all solutions to using a `Stream` & `StreamBuilder` and listening for any changes.

**Commonly one uses this approach:**

```
Stream<UserModel?> getFirestoreUser(String uid) {
  return FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users').doc(uid).snapshots().map((event) => event.data()).map((event) => event == null ? null : UserModel.fromJson(event));
}
```

**where:**

- `UserModel` has a `fromJson(Map<String, dynamic>)` factory constructor
- and where there exists a `users` collection with the document ID being `uid`.

Stream returns a `Stream<UserModel?>` that can be used later by a `Provider.of<UserModel?>(context)` or in a `StreamBuider<UserModel?>`

---

**Problem:**

TL;DR - after a `Firestore().getCurrentUser(uid)` stream is updated (directly, or manually using firestore emulator and changing the document values), the `StreamBuilder<UserModel?>` below doesn't update.

At all points in app lifecycle (authenticated or not), the stream always returns null (however manually invoking the stream with `.first` returns the user content, but `.last` just hangs). See below for more info.

Link to [github project](https://github.com/cybex-dev/flutter-firestore-streambuilder).

**To get started:**

1. Throw in your own `gooogle-services.json` file into `android/app` folder
2. change all references for `com.flutterprojects.myapp` to `${your google-services.json package name}`
3. Use local emulator to update firestore changes

**More Details:**

My issue uses a similar approach, yet the `Stream` doesn't return anything. My Flutter widget `LoggedIn()` is used when the `FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser` is valid (i.e. not null)

```
class LoggedIn extends StatelessWidget{
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // TODO: implement build
    return StreamBuilder<UserModel?>(
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        print("Checking UserModel from stream provider");
        if (snapshot.data == null) {
          print("UserModel is null");
          return UiLogin();
        }

        print("UserModel is NOT null");
        return UiHome();
      },
    );
  }
}
```

After a successful authentication, the text `Checking UserModel from stream provider` is printed to the console, then `UserModel is null`. At no point does `UserModel is NOT null` get shown.

After successful authentication (i.e. user registered & document updated), I have a button that I manually invoke the stream and get the first item:

```
var currentUser = Firestore().getCurrentUser(FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid);
var first = await currentUser.first;
print(first);
```

which returns the `UserModel` based on the newly added user information.

When running the following code, execution stops on `.last`, no error, no crash, no app exit, just stops executing.

```
var currentUser = Firestore().getCurrentUser(FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid);
var last = await currentUser.last;
print(last);
```

BUT

When adding the following, any changes gets updated and printed to the console

```
Firestore().getCurrentUser(currentUid).listen((data) {
    print("Firestore Data Changed");
    print("Firestore change value: $data");
});
```

This means the `StreamBuilder<UserModel?>` isn't working correctly, as the `Stream<UserModel>` events do `listen()` to changes and acknowledge those changes, but the `StreamBuilder<UserModel?>` changes do not get affected and consistently returns `null`.

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Have you added the `stream:` argument to StreamBuilder?

Answer (score 0):

Try  `if (snapshot.hasData) { print("UserModel is null"); return UiLogin(); }`

Comment: `snapshot.hasData` is a glorified `snapshot.data != null` check which I am already doing, see https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/AsyncSnapshot/hasData.html. How will this help?

Answer (score 0):

This is working for me. Maybe the connection states are what's missing.

```
StreamBuilder(
        stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
            .collection('users')
            .doc(widget.uid)
            .collection('contacts')
            .doc(widget.client)
            .collection('messages')
            .orderBy('timestamp', descending: true)
            .snapshots(),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasError)
            return Expanded(
              child: Center(child: Text('Problem Getting Your Messages')),
            );

          switch (snapshot.connectionState) {
            case ConnectionState.none:
              return Text('waiting');
            case ConnectionState.waiting:
              return Center(child: Text('Waiting'));
            case ConnectionState.active:
              var snap;
              print('active');
              if (snapshot.data != null) {
                snap = snapshot.data;
              }
              return Expanded(
                child: ListView(
                  ...
              );

            case ConnectionState.done:
              print('done');
              return Text('Lost Connection');
          }

          return Text('NOPE');
        },
      ),
```